# 15.10 - No menubar at the top of xournal 4.8, making the program unusable

Tags: 15.10, installed-programs

I'm trying to use xournal 4.8 as a note taking program, and there is alot of options in it that would be really useful to me.. if I could access them.

Currently, when I option this, there is no menubar the top, no options/file/etc things:
[image: Xournal w/ no menubar]

Googling this issue yielded no results, and it's making the program literally not usable. It is version 4.8-1

How can I fix this? It's important for me to be able to take notes on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Xournal** like other applications will have its menu integrated in the global menu on the top bar. It will appear on hovering the mouse there:

[image]

In case we would like the menu to appear in the application's window we can change this as an option in *System Settings > Appearance > Behaviour*:

[image]

The menus will then appear on hovering the mouse over the application window's title bar.

Comment: This didn't show the menu for me. After saving the file, the menues have disappeared and do not appear in any way. (Ubuntu 18)